# Including openCV .jar file to a web project

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, opencv, jar

I'm trying to run openCV library on a java web project using eclipse, and the steps I followed  are shown in this link :
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#java-dev-intro

The problem is, in the web project we have to put the .jar files in the WEB-INF/bin folder, so in my case its a user library not a jar file, and when I compile the code it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java246 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
```

Can you help me importing the native library in other way ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "so in my case its a user library not a jar file", i thought you were just putting the jar file in WEB-INF/bin folder

Comment: Well, I tested the OpenCV in a normal java application after following the steps in the link above to create a user library and import the jar file and the native library inside it and it works fine ! but in the web application its not just a jar file, as shown in the steps above you have to put the jar AND the native library in the user library, but that doesn't work in web applications, what should I do in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Web application your "*.jar" should be in the lib folder. because internally Server can recognize the .jar file only in he lib folder.
Folder Structure:

```
  rootfolder
        *.jsp

        WEB-INF
            classes
            lib
              *.jar
```

means WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

Then it compile nicely.

Comment: Thanks @Mohsin but thats not my problem, I know that already and I mentioned it in my question. My problem is when I follow the steps shown in the opencv tutorial (the link ) it won't work !

Answer (score 0):

Before running the project in server, you have to add **-Djava.library.path** in **VM arguments** of your server.

To add **-Djava.library.path**, follow the path

**Project->Run As->Run Configurations**

After that,

Choose **Arguments** tab and in the **VM arguments** textarea add the following attribute

-Djava.library.path="OpenCV/OpenCV 2.4.11/opencv/build/java/x64"

[Check another possible duplicate stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853509/opencv-unable-to-load-library-for-a-dynamic-web-project#)